# Is it possible to join someone to help them with the border security process at the airport?

Tags: customs-and-immigration, ireland, turkish-citizens, dub

As a Turkish citizen, I have lived in Ireland for over a year now. My wife is planning to visit me before the end of the year. She will board a plane from Turkey, and I will pick her up from the airport.

After she sets foot in to Ireland, she will have to pass border security without me, but her English skills are lacking.

Is there any way for me to join her for this process with my passport? Can I ask the police to let me inside the zone, collect her bags, or/and accompany her during the border security process?

Comment: Depends on the airport - I know in Cairo our tour group met us at the gate and helped us through security.  Your best bet is likely to call the Dublin airport and ask - they'll have some advice.

Comment: If you can't get in, it might be helpful to write a letter, in English, and send it to her. The letter could explain what language(s) she speaks, and that her husband is waiting outside and could translate for her.

Comment: @PatriciaShanahan that's an awesome idea, thanks!

Comment: @Mark I will definitely do that at the end, just wanted to have a brief idea. Thanks.

Comment: I edited the tags.  Please note that [tag:airport-security] is for the security process that takes place before boarding, to keep people from bringing dangerous items on the plane.  For the process that occurs after landing to decide if you and your goods may enter a country, please use [tag:customs-and-immigration].  Also, I took a guess that the airport in question is Dublin (DUB); if not, please edit the tag.

Comment: At Dublin you can't, because of the Airport design. In Zurich it is possible (though not officially allowed) and I often do it to help friends. I just walk behind someone past the boarding pass gate, then go through security and passport control, then take the escalator down to the arrivals corridor and meet the Person/people there

Comment: @Crazydre, I am not looking for sneaking out, but to ask for it. Maybe they don't mind what you are doing in Zurich though.

Comment: @NecatiHakanErdogan Your surest means would be calling Dublin Airport and asking

Comment: Craz ...  "I just walk behind someone past the boarding pass gate..." that is astounding, absolutely amazing.  Bravo!

Comment: @Crazydre So, er, how many acts of deception are you committing to "help" people, here? "Hi, border officer. I'm Fred and this is my friend Crazydre. Please pay no attention to the fact that he blagged his way into the secure area without a boarding pass (which is illegal in some countries) and is now claiming to you that he instead arrived on a plane from X-land. He's very trustworthy."

Comment: @Crazydre Being able to enter or leave the Schengen area as you please has nothing to do with entering the secure area of the airport. Going into the secure area is not "entering or exiting the Schengen area": you were already in Switzerland and you were walking into a different part of Switzerland.

Comment: @DavidRicherby Guess I expressed it a bit clumsily. Of course it's not the same Thing - my point was that I go into the secure area every now and then and not **only** when picking up others

Comment: @Crazydre And I was probably a bit confusing two. What I meant was, each time you help somebody through immigration, how many lies are you telling? I count at least two: gaining entry to the secure area without a boarding pass, and telling the immigration officer that you're travelling with the people you're helping. Lies are not good support to an immigration case. Entering the securing area without a boarding pass may be specifically illegal. This is not a good idea.

Comment: Can confirm what @PatriciaShanahan suggested - we've done this several times already. In our letter we explained who the arriving person is, who we are and why we invite her. We gave all our details, reasons for living in Ireland and contacts. All in all, as many details as possible. And the arriving person just printed it out and presented at border control. As a result, officers never asked a single question and we never had a single problem in such situations

Comment: @DavidRicherby - "What I meant was ..." While this might be "Lying" or "Illegal", it is not necessarily so. He didn't say he snuck (sneaked) around and bypassed security checkpoints or told lies to gain access. If they let him through then he was allowed through. I agree that this would not likely be allowed in most places, but to be honest, I haven't visited most places.

Comment: @KevinFegan "I just walk behind someone past the boarding pass gate" suggests very strongly to me that he _is_ sneaking into the secure area, by tailgating somebody through the gate that's designed to only allow people with boarding passes through. Now to the immigration officer. Questions that they typically ask include things like "Are you travelling together?" "What is the purpose of your visit?" and any answer other than "Actually, I didn't even travel. I got into the secure area from landside for the sole purpose of taking part in this interview." is a lie.

Comment: @DavidRicherby - I agree that "I just walk behind someone past the boarding pass gate" sounds sneaky, but I'm not sure it rises to the level of "illegal". After all, doesn't everyone "just walk behind the person in front of them past the boarding pass gate". The next part of the statement was "then go through security and passport control". I assume he has to present his identification (passport) to them and explain why he has no boarding pass and what his purpose for being there is. There is no indication in what he said that he lied. ...

Comment: @DavidRicherby ... If they allow him through, then it means he is allowed there. Of course, if he does lie about his purpose there, then that would most likely be illegal and certainly not worth the risk.

Comment: @KevinFegan Don't be so literal. People don't usually mention things unless they're relevant, so what do you think the relevance of walking behind somebody through a gate is, if it's not tailgating? Passport control just care if you have a passport; security just care that you're not carrying weapons or other illegal items. None of these people check boarding cards. If he was being allowed through, surely he'd say that: it would be so much easier. As it is, he's explicitly said it is "not officially allowed".

Answer (score 51, accepted):

I have had this type of situation a lot: a relative or friend wants to attend the landing interview to assist with translating and to otherwise help comfort the arriving passenger.

It's not going to happen at non-EU arrival ports in the [Common Travel Area](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Common_Travel_Area) except when the Immigration Officer (or An Garda Síochána) invites the friend or relative to attend and that would be an extraordinary situation. It invites security issues like the transfer of contraband for example. Consider a flight from Turkey that has 250+ passengers and each of them wants a friend or relative to attend the landing interview. Now what? They are supposed to flood a secured area with those people? No chance.   They *especially* do not like mixed gender interviews if the passenger is female and arriving from a South Asian locale because it drags in [implications](https://www.gov.uk/guidance/forced-marriage) of what might be taking place.

Even in the case of removal they will not allow it. It gets even more complicated if [arriving children](http://www.legislation.gov.uk/ukpga/2004/31) need to be removed.

The authorities are supposed to have translators either present at the port or on call for telephone access. In the rare event they want to speak to you they will contact you by phone or seek you out in the passenger greeting gallery.  I have advised relatives and friends to be sure the passenger carries a photo to help the officer spot the person rather than to use the public address.

Also remember that most non-English speaking, non-EU passengers have an entry clearance (or its counterpart, the Irish Visitor Visa) through which the 'heavy lifting' has been already been done.

Alternatively, the larger ports in the CTA have VIP services you can use, but the most common remedy is to have the passenger carry a letter.  They will not pay much attention to it, but it may help ease your mind.  Also you can join the flight at a leg outside the CTA.

Overall, trying to get in to the secured area violates a **prime rule of travelling**: *avoid anything likely to set off an IO's radar*. As always, it's vital to be in the arrivals gallery and have your mobile at the ready.

---

Adding: there's a special corner case for people who want to receive blessings from an arriving Swami or Marabout and ***insist*** on being allowed air side. Things can escalate into religious fervour very quickly when the plane has landed and the authorities will begin to worry. To help avoid potential riots, DUB, LHR, and LGW have a secured room set aside for blessings from swamis and other types of holy individuals, and blessings always take place after the landing interview anyway.

---

Note: this answer is scoped to living humans only. The arrival of horses, livestock, household pets, penguins (zoo specimens) etc is an *utterly different* can of worms. Especially getting air side to 'greet' one's horses.

Comment: "The arrival of horses, ... etc is an utterly different can of worms" - perhaps especially so if the "etc" is actually worms? ;-)

Answer (score 20):

My in-laws don't speak English. Whenever they come to visit, we send them a letter to show to the Immigration Officers explaining:

- who they are
- that they don't speak English
- why they're coming to UK
- where they will stay
- a bank statement showing we can provide for them while they stay here (they never asked to see this, but driving back from France once the officer asked if we had the means to provide for my mother-in-law)

Remember to be polite in the letter.

It's also a good idea to put your phone number in the letter so if they need to speak to you they know where to call.

Never had an issue.

Comment: @pnuts Sorry, I missed that.

Answer (score 18):

There is one easy, non-suspicious, canonical way to do this: fly to Turkey, fly back with her, and go through immigration/border security together.

Comment: Spending hundreds of dollars on airfare and 8+ hours on a plane to ultimately walk a few hundred feet with his wife doesn't sound "easy" to me.

Comment: International border crossings are damn scary, especially for someone who does not have citizenship-privilege (e.g. US or EU) and who is not proficient in the language. It never ceases to amaze me how people will try to skimp on a few hundred (or at most a thousand or so) dollars as insurance and comfort/support for their spouse in cases like this.

Comment: Even cheaper: get a non-direct flight via a nearby country and then just buy a ticket for the second leg.

Comment: Perhaps, but given the specific security environment right now with Turkey and its close neighbors (namely Syria and ISIS territory) I highly recommend *against* flying to Turkey for a quick turnaround. I would assume that sets off security measures you may not want to be part of.

Comment: @BruceWayne: Yes, the non-direct-flight approach sounds better.

Comment: @JonathanReez: that just relocates the problem to the nearby country, doesn't it?

Comment: @TonyK: Not if you don't have to go through immigration for transit in that country/airport. But it may be hard to figure out whether that's the case.

Comment: @R.. it doesn't just have to be convenience that stops people from doing the turnaround. The OP might very well be the sole income earner of the household, unable to easily and suddenly take the minimum 12 hours of time it would take because of work responsibilities (or other inconveniences).

Comment: R.., Thanks but I already know if I buy a ticket for hundreds of Euros, fly back and take the same plane with her and waste my whole day... Yes I can be with her during the process. I am looking for an easier way.

Answer (score 4):

As **Gayot Fow** mentioned, it's probably impossible for you to join your wife from landside in Ireland. However what you **can** do (this was suggested by Gayot as well) is make sure both of you are on the same plane. The easiest way to pull it off is:

1. Have your wife buy a ticket from Turkey to Ireland via an intermediate airport X
2. Buy yourself two tickets: one from Ireland to the intermediate X airport and one from X to Ireland (the same leg as the one your wife will be flying on)
3. Once your wife lands in X, join her at the gate and fly together to Ireland

Possible options for X: Frankfurt, Paris, Amsterdam. Others can be found via flight search engines depending on your dates.

Comment: @TRiG oops, fixed

Comment: @pnuts I wanted to provide a more exact description on how to pull it off cheaply

Comment: @pnuts answer fixed

Answer (score 2):

Assuming your wife has a suitable visa, I wouldn't worry too much about this. Whilst a visa is not a guarantee of entry, unless the visa holder presents as a security risk, the border guard is unlikely to overrule the decision represented by the visa. The best idea would be to contact the border service (this can be the tricky part!) and convey that your wife has little English so if they want to question her extensively they need to provide a translator. At this point they may suggest you attend to translate for her - do not suggest it up front though, this would appear suspicious.

If she doesn't have a visa, than overall it's going to be more tricky and you may have to think about flying in with her.